# ghostscript preserve PDF input's font

Tags: pdf, fonts, pdf-generation, ghostscript

My ghostscript command is this:

```
gs \
    -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE \
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
    -dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged \
    -dDownsampleMonoImages=false \
    -dDownsampleGrayImages=false \
    -dDownsampleColorImages=false \
    -dAutoFilterColorImages=false \
    -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false \
    -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode \
    -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode \
    -sOutputFile=./merge.pdf \
    -f ./page_*.pdf
```

Most of the command are related to images.

After execution, I find that the fonts look less sharp than the input file.
The difference between the fonts is as follows:

Fonts of (one of) the input file:

```
$ pdffonts page_3.pdf 
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
NachlieliCLM-Bold                    Type 1            Builtin          yes no  yes     62  0
NachlieliCLM-Bold                    Type 1            Custom           yes no  yes     65  0
Courier10PitchBT-Bold                Type 1            Builtin          yes no  yes     70  0
EAAAAA+LiberationSerif               TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     27  0
NachlieliCLM-Light                   Type 1            Builtin          yes no  yes     75  0
NachlieliCLM-Light                   Type 1            Custom           yes no  yes     78  0
HAAAAA+LiberationSans-Bold           TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     42  0
IAAAAA+DejaVuSans                    TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     47  0
JAAAAA+LMMono9-Regular               Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes     52  0
KAAAAA+LMMonoProp10-Regular          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes     37  0
Courier10PitchBT-Roman               Type 1            Builtin          yes no  yes     83  0
MAAAAA+LiberationSerif-Bold          TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     57  0
NAAAAA+LiberationSerif-Italic        TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     32  0
```

Font of the output file:

```
$ pdffonts merge.pdf 
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
LQRJGW+LiberationSerif-Bold          TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     54  0
ZAZOKA+NachlieliCLM-Light            Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes     42  0
XFXEQZ+LiberationSerif-Italic        TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     56  0
KBCNYY+LiberationSans-Bold           TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     44  0
PPEMTT+DejaVuSans                    TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     46  0
FUVLBK+NachlieliCLM-Bold             Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes     36  0
OQFKGW+LMMono9-Regular               Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      48  0
ZFATCB+LMMonoProp10-Regular          Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      50  0
WIGEDL+Courier10PitchBT-Bold         Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      38  0
AFLCKO+Courier10PitchBT-Roman        Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      52  0
QNUNTR+LiberationSerif               TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     40  0
BLSWAW+DejaVuSansMono                TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     97  0
HQDKJN+LiberationSerif               TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     99  0
SCAKLE+LiberationSerif-Italic        TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes    101  0
AGALJA+NachlieliCLM-Bold             Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes     91  0
PPEMTT+DejaVuSans                    TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes    103  0
TLVEAY+LiberationSans-Bold           TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     93  0
GLOKSW+NachlieliCLM-Light            Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes     95  0
```

The only method which PARTIALLY works is executing the following:

```
gs \
    -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE \
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
    -dCompressFonts=true \
    -dSubsetFonts=true \
    -dEmbedAllFonts=false \
    -sOutputFile=./merge.pdf \
    -f ./page_*.pdf

$ pdffonts merge.pdf 
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
LQRJGW+LiberationSerif-Bold          TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     54  0
NachlieliCLM-Light                   Type 1            Custom           no  no  yes     42  0
XFXEQZ+LiberationSerif-Italic        TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     56  0
KBCNYY+LiberationSans-Bold           TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     44  0
PPEMTT+DejaVuSans                    TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     46  0
NachlieliCLM-Bold                    Type 1            Custom           no  no  yes     36  0
EVJWAP+LMMono9-Regular               Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      48  0
LAKFSN+LMMonoProp10-Regular          Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      50  0
Courier10PitchBT-Bold                Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no      38  0
Courier10PitchBT-Roman               Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no      52  0
QNUNTR+LiberationSerif               TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     40  0
BLSWAW+DejaVuSansMono                TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     97  0
HQDKJN+LiberationSerif               TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     99  0
SCAKLE+LiberationSerif-Italic        TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes    101  0
NachlieliCLM-Bold                    Type 1            Custom           no  no  yes     91  0
PPEMTT+DejaVuSans                    TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes    103  0
TLVEAY+LiberationSans-Bold           TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     93  0
NachlieliCLM-Light                   Type 1            Custom           no  no  yes     95  0
```

In the last case - the font `LMMono9` doesn't change, but the font `NachlieliCLM` is sharper (probably due to that it is not embedded...).
As you can see - some of the fonts aren't embedded - which is bad.
The output PDF is intended for printing and sharing, therefore the fonts needs to be embedded and in high quality.

BTW, I know that the flags need to be as such:

```
-dCompressFonts=true \
-dSubsetFonts=false \
-dEmbedAllFonts=true \
```

But the fonts still not sharp with these flags.

I've read many SO threads and in documentation but failed to find a solution.
I suspect that I need the output font to be of type `Type 1`, instead of type `Type 1C`, but not sure.

---

### Example:

There are attached two files: [input.pdf](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=33792302979232240776) and [output.pdf](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=05211221957456885974).
There is a difference between them ONLY in the following text:

- "Title is here (heading 2)" - Font is `Courier 10 Pitch`
- Bullets "First" up to and including "Sixth" - Font is `LM Mono 9`
  (Notice that the rest of the sentence in the bullets is fine - it doesn't change. Meaning that only the word numbers, like "First", are the ones who change.)
- The last/bottom (Hebrew) sentence  - Font is `Nachlieli CLM`

The difference is that in the output file, the text is more gross. (input is sharper).  In order to see the difference, place the two PDF documents side by side, each having a zoom of 100%. The difference is noticeable with using either Ubuntu's default `Document Viewer` or `Okular`.
The rest of the text is the same.
Also indeed the input PDF file was created using LibreOffice 4.2.
The output file was created using the following command:

```
gs \
    -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE \
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
    -dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged \
    -dDownsampleMonoImages=false \
    -dDownsampleGrayImages=false \
    -dDownsampleColorImages=false \
    -dAutoFilterColorImages=false \
    -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false \
    -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode \
    -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode \
    -sOutputFile=./output.pdf \
    -f ./input.pdf
```

I'm using GPL Ghostscript 9.10 and Ubuntu 14.04.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4aQH.png) to show the differences between input (pre-GS) and output (post GS). Used the software `Document Viewer 3.10` (or Evince).

Comment: Maybe something like [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) would suit your needs better, just download the ..app.jar and try `java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.0-RC3.jar PDFMerger ./page_*.pdf merge.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

No the font format is not an issue. Type 1C is simply CFF format which is (more or less) a more compact representation of a type 1 font.

You don't say which operating system you are using, nor which version of Ghostscript.

Its not possible to tell you anything about what is happening without an example. Please post an input file somewhere where we can look at it and then we might be able to help you.

Converting to type 1C is a simple matter and does not affect the font 'sharpness' since both are vector forms. You will not get a type 1 font out of pdfwrite, all type 1 fonts are converted to CFF (type 1C).

The reason NachlieliCLM is not embedded is that have set EmbedAllFonts=false, and its not subset and uses the default Encoding. A subset input font needs to be embedded, because it almost invariably uses a custom Encoding, so you can't simply use the original font in its place.

I **suspect**, but can't prove without seeing the input, that your problem is due to the poor naming convention used by certain PDF-producing applications. The subset is not unique, causing name collisions. LibreOffice is a known culprit here.

That problem was believed resolved recently (we now additionally use the PDF object number as well the font name) but since I don't know what version of Ghostscript you are using I can't say whether that's likely to be the problem. However that normally causes incorrect characters, not a loss of 'sharpness' which is more likely to be caused by rendering to an image.

As I said, post a (small) example input file and the result you get from Ghostscript and pdfwrite, and it might be possible to say more.

Comment: Dear KenS, I added all the info you requested in my question.

Comment: Well you are using an old version of Ghostscript, the current version is 9.19. The version you are using is too old to have the update that resolves the subset problem with poorly written PDF files. I will get the example files and take a quick look at those.

Comment: So exactly which piece of text do you see as a problem ? Also what are you using to view the PDF ? Using Adobe Acrobat the 2 files look identical to me.

Comment: Indeed [it is old](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/%2Bsource/ghostscript) but that is the only available version (via Ubuntu Software Center). The answers to all the new questions is already in my first post :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not the most recent version of Ghostscript on Ubuntu, Till usually keeps Ubuntu right up to date, but if he shows up in IRC I'll check with him. Other than that, I cannot see a difference using Acrobat, perhaps the difference is actually down to the viewer you are using ? FWIW hte current version does a better job in my opinion, so its possible if you were to use the current version of Ghostscript it might show an improvement for you.

Comment: Yes it is the most recent - you can see in the [link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/%2Bsource/ghostscript) in my previous comment - for `Trusty Tahr` (i.e. Ubuntu 14.04) then `ghostscript 9.10` is the latest.
Besides of `Okular` and Ubuntu's default `Document Viewer`, I tried also `qpdfview` (recommended [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/181820/5698)) and the results are the same.. perhaps Adobe Acrobat render the text differently? IDK..

Comment: Well I cannot see any difference on Acrobat, perhaps you could post a screenshot. Or perhaps try the latest version of Ghostscript. A 2year old version is not the most recent

Comment: I added a screenshot (in original/first post). I didn't know that my GS version is 2 years old! That's really old. Please encourage Till to update this..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how current your question is but today I faced a similar issue as yours and I found out using pdffonts that my output after merging does not contain the same fonts as my source resulting in unsharp and unpretty characters. I solved the problem in putting all fonts used by the input in a specific folder and then I called ghostscript with following arguments:

```
gs -sFONTPATH=<my_folder> \
   -dEmbedAllFonts=true \
   -sOutputFile=<my_output>.pdf \
   <my_input>.pdf
```

Input and output pdfs matched after that! BTW: I am currectly using gs 9.25.0

Comment: you are wright, thanks! But upgrading to 9.25 or even 10.0 should not change anything...

Comment: with my old canonic 9.25 version <my_folder> has not to be slash terminated